# Now what is the correct variable that the inhlat greater than 5GB deletes all this data in the folder

Tags: powershell

```
$sum = (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\test501 -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum

gci Downloads -Dir -r | %{$_.FullName; ((gci -File $_.FullName | measure Length -Sum).Sum) /1GB }
```

Comment: What is "inhlat"?

Comment: I guess `content` (from inhalt)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Browse through a set of folders, deterimine their total size? (and if > 5Gb delete all that as the title sort-of suggests) ??